# Multithreading: How to get a thread to execute more frequently than the others?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I've recently been learning about semaphores to specify the ordering of threads, but I'm curious about how to control the frequency as well. Below is a program that prints *, a digit, and then a letter to the screen. Always in that order (e.g. *1A).  How can I make it so certain threads print more than once before the others? (e.g. *32A)

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ThreadSync {
    private static boolean runFlag = true;
    private static Semaphore canPrintSymbol = new Semaphore(1);
    private static Semaphore canPrintDigit = new Semaphore(0);
    private static Semaphore canPrintLetter = new Semaphore(0);

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Runnable[] tasks = new Runnable[17];
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[17];

        // Create 10-digit threads
        for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
            tasks[d] = new PrintDigit((char)('0' + d));
            threads[d] = new Thread(tasks[d]);
            threads[d].start();
        }
        // Create 6-letter threads
        for (int d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
            tasks[d + 10] = new PrintLetter((char)('A' + d));
            threads[d + 10] = new Thread(tasks[d + 10]);
            threads[d + 10].start();
        }
        // Create a thread to print asterisk
        tasks[16] = new PrintSymbol('*');
        threads[16] = new Thread(tasks[16]);
        threads[16].start();

        // Let the threads run for a period of time
        try { Thread.sleep(500); } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

        runFlag = false;

        // Interrupt the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) threads[i].interrupt();
    }

    public static class PrintSymbol implements Runnable {
        private char c;
        public PrintSymbol(char c) { 
            this.c = c; 
        }

        public void run() {
            while (runFlag) {
                try {
                    canPrintSymbol.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.printf("%c\n", c);
                canPrintDigit.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PrintDigit implements Runnable {
        private char c;
        public PrintDigit(char c) { this.c=c; }
        public void run() {
            while (runFlag) {
                try {
                    canPrintDigit.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.printf("%c\n", c);
                canPrintLetter.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PrintLetter implements Runnable {
        private char c;
        public PrintLetter(char c) { 
            this.c = c; 
        }

        public void run() {
            while (runFlag) {
                try {
                    canPrintLetter.acquire();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.printf("%c\n", c);
                canPrintSymbol.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ochi No, he doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is you can't. At least not to my knowledge. There are hints you can give to the OS like yielding your thread. This means it yields it processing to the next thread. Other then that all you can really do is influence the priority. But all these are just hints to the OS. The OS ultimately determines the order in which the threads are executed. This is one of the main things to keep in mind when working with multiple threads. It is generally not a good idea to have a dependency between separate threads which makes the order of execution important.

Comment: What if I were to create two more semaphores (an additional one for printing digits and an additional one for printing characters)? Could that give me the desired output?